# Table where an element depends on the sum of previous elements

Tags: recursion

I'm trying to create a table whose elements will be a sum over previously declared elements up to a certain iteration. I've reduced what I'm trying to do to the simplest form (posted below):

```
M[x_] := M[x] = Table[
   If[
    n == 1, r, 2 x^n Sum[M[x][[i]], {i, 1, n-1}]
    ],
   {n, 1, 5}]
```

When I evaluate the above expression, it produces an exceedingly long expression that is obviously wrong. What's the mistake that I'm making here?

Comment: `M[x]` only references itself here, so it will be an infinite recursion. When you call `M[1]` for instance, the RHS contains a sum over the elements of `M[1]`.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand. Why would it be an infinite recursion? Say for instance, we're on the iteratino n=2 then it should sum from i=1 to i=1 and the expression should be 2x^n M[x][[1]] where x could now be specified. Right?

Comment: Each item `M[x]` is referenced it must call itself to determine its value. `Table` must complete and return a value to `M[x]` before `M[x]` can be assigned a value. Since the looping is happening inside of `Table` the calls in `Table` to `M[x]` are causing `M[x]` to be called again in a never ending loop.

Comment: Have you seen `RecurrenceTable[]`?

Comment: If I wanted to set the ith element to be the sum of all previous elements would RecurrenceTable[] be able to do the job?

Comment: Yes; use `Sum[]`…

Answer (score 5):

I think `FoldList` is what you are looking for.

```
m[x_] := FoldList[#1 + #1 2 x^#2 &, Prepend[r]@Range[2, 3]]
```

Then

```
m[y]
```

> {r, r + 2 r y^2, r + 2 r y^2 + 2 y^3 (r + 2 r y^2)}

Just need to change the `3` to a `5`.

Hope this helps.